# Pycrypto string too long to sign/verify

Tags: python, rsa, digital-signature, pycrypto

I have this code, but when I run it, it only accepts "to_address" variable of a certain lenth. When it is too long, I receive an exception:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
** IDLE Internal Exception: 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 325, in runcode
    exec code in self.locals
  File "C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 111, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\Queue.py", line 176, in get
    raise Empty
Empty
```

This is my code:

```
import hashlib
import sqlite3
import socket
import time
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# import keys
key_file = open('keys.pem','r')
key = RSA.importKey(key_file.read())
public_key = key.publickey()
private_key_readable = str(key.exportKey())
public_key_readable = str(key.publickey().exportKey())
address = hashlib.sha224(public_key_readable).hexdigest()

to_address = str(raw_input ("Send to address: "))
amount = str(raw_input ("How much to send: "))
timestamp = str(time.time())

transaction = str(timestamp) +":"+ str(address) +":"+ str(to_address) +":"+ str(amount)
signature = key.sign(transaction, '')
print "Client: Signature: "+str(signature)

if public_key.verify(transaction, signature) == True:
    if int(amount) < 0:
        print "Client: Signature OK, but cannot use negative amounts"

    else:
        ...process...

else:
    print "Client: Invalid signature"
    raise
#enter transaction end
```

If anyone knows how to go around this length limitation, it would be appreciated. Do I need to encrypt the string somehow to make it shorter in order to verify it and then decrypt it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps sign a hash of the transaction. At verification time you can take the hash again verify that.

Regarding the signing of messages, the documentation says:

> The piece of data to sign with RSA. It may not be numerically larger
>   than the RSA module (n).

Watch out though. The documentation for `sign` and `verify` says:

> Attention: this function performs the plain, primitive RSA encryption
>   (textbook). In real applications, you always need to use proper
>   cryptographic padding, and you should not directly verify data with
>   this method. Failure to do so may lead to security vulnerabilities. It
>   is recommended to use modules Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_PSS or
>   Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5 instead.

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#publickey